# Making a Bigchaindb Network

Tags: mongodb, tendermint, bigchaindb

Can anyone help me  in making a bigchaindb network with 3 nodes.I tried and created network by following http://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/latest/simple-deployment-template/network-setup.html this link .After running monit process on each node iam getting **panic error initializing db resource temporarily unavailable**.But i can see mongodb status as active and bigchain db has been created.

Comment: Please add proper explanation and code snippets or errors that you are facing.

Comment: after runnning the nodes i got panic error :initializing db resource temporarily unavailable. but Mongodb is running in backend and bigchain database has been created.

Comment: Please edit your question and update.